# How to do nested loop to search the string in a file

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 excel file having thousands of data.I want to take the row from file1 and search the entire file2 and output the repeated to file3.

```
   file 1                        file2                      file3
 abc.bcg@gmail.com            abc.bcg_12253              abc.bcg_12253
 bcg.abc@gmail.com            efx.rfz_12345              def.xyz_08345
  def.xyz@gmail.com           wqr.qtf_34567
                              zxc.mnb_98764
                              def.xyz_08345
```

---

```
       FileReader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for row in FileReader:
                    emailLegalFile = row['email']
                    name_emailFile = emailFile[:emailLegalFile.find('@')]
                    print name_emailLegalFile

                    #with open(inputfile, 'rb') as d:
                    inputFileReader = csv.DictReader(d)
                    for r in inputFileReader:
                            if name_emailFile in  r['google_email']:
                                    date = r['date']
                                    time = r['time']
                                    t_format = r['format']
                                    file_size = r['file_size']
                                    google_email = r['google_email']

                                    #writer = csv.writer(w)

                                    #dic = {'date': date, 'time':time,'format':t_format,'file_size':file_size, 'google_email':google_email}

                                    #writer.writerow(dic)
                                    list = [date,time,t_format,file_size,google_email]

                                    with open('result.csv','a') as e:
                                            writer_1 = csv.writer(e,delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                                            writer_1.writerow(list)
```

File2 has 5 columns, but wanted to match with the 5th column only.

The output I am getting is just the 1st value i.e. abc.bcg_12253.

Please help me in solving this.

Thank you

Comment: Where do you open the file d?  In the posted code it is commented out.  If it's being opened outside of the outer For loop, you will probably need to rewind the file before initializing the DictReader again, ie d.seek(0) before inputFileReader = csv.DictReader(d)